# Improving skin color and shining through diet

Tags: diet, dermatology, coloration-discoloration, juice, melanin

From the research on web I found that drinking [carrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot) and [beetroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetroot) juice is very good for skin health (i.e. improving skin colour, shining etc.)

However, both juices are used to loose weight, while I want to gain weight.

Are there any other foods with similar effects?

Comment: There's nothing magic about carrot or beetroot juice that makes you lose weight.  Weight loss is entirely about calorie balance: whether you are using more calories than you consume or vice-versa.

Comment: Really thank you friend . But i heard that apart from low calorie value , these both vegetable have a some vitamins that help to lose weight .